# How can grammar from RFC 2396 (about URI) be expressed in PEG?

Tags: parsing, uri, grammar, peg

I am trying to come up with a PEG grammar that would parse a hostname according the following BNF of [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#appendix-A)

```
  hostname      = *( domainlabel "." ) toplabel [ "." ]
  domainlabel   = alphanum | alphanum *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
  toplabel      = alpha | alpha *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
```

There is no problem with `domainlabel` and `toplabel`.

The rule for `hostname` however, it seems, cannot be expressed in PEG.

Here is why I think so:

If we take the grammar as written in BNF the whole input is consumed by `*(domainlabel ".")` which doesn't know when to stop since `toplabel [ "." ]` is indistinguishable from it.

simplified self-contained illustration:

```
h = (d '.')* t '.'?
d = [dt]
t = [t]
```

This would parse `t`, `d.d.t` and fail on `d.d.d` which is totally expected, but it fails to parse `t.` and `d.d.t.` which both are valid cases.

If we add a lookahead then it would consume `t.` and `d.d.t.`, but fail on `d.t.t.`.

```
h = (!(t '.'?)d '.')* t '.'?
d = [dt]
t = [t]
```

So I am out of ideas, is there a way to express this BNF in PEG?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check validity, you can do it like this:

```
/* Unchanged */
toplabel      = alpha | alpha *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
/* Diff with above */
nontoplabel   = digit | digit *( alphanum | "-" ) alphanum
/* Rephrase */
hostname      = 1*( *( nontoplabel "." ) toplabel) [ "." ]
```

Since `nontoplabel` and `toplabel` are distinguishable by their first character, there is no possible ambiguity in the last expression.

The transformation is one of the many possible regular expression identities:

```
(a | b)* a ==> (b* a)+
```

You can always replace `b` in `a|b` with `b-a` (using `-` as the set difference operator).

Comment: I am interested about your last point on the rewrite of `a|b`. Can you give some references?

Comment: @seki: it's just simple set theory, since `|` is the union of two sets. A set doesn't have duplicate elements, so when you compute the union of A and B, you can remove from B the elements already in the union because they are in A.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)